# Is there standard notation to handle "chains of functions"?

Tags: functions, notation

Let
$f(x)=g  $

$g(y)=z  $

Is there standard notation to express z in terms of f(x)? Something like (f(x))(y)?

Comment: Yes, there is a standard notation: $z=g(y)=g(f(x))=(g\circ f)(x).$ It is called the function composition.

Comment: @Manuel: The question is $f(x) = g$, not $f(x) = y$.

Comment: @Manuel: I think is not a composition. If you look at it, $\text{f}(x) = g$ where _g_ is another function. I thought something like $\text{f}(x)(y) = z$ but that is not quite right either.

Comment: You can write $\left( f(x) \right)(y)$ if you want to use a lot of parentheses.

Comment: In my opinion it is the most common notation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always written $f(x)(y)$. In my opinion, it's clear that evaluation should be left associative, so no need for the extra set of parentheses. Some contexts (e.g. $\lambda$-calculus) would even just write $fxy$